# How to customize a view inside AlertDialog Single choice?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to customize my view in AlertDialog single choice like in this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIAy7.png)

How can make like this?

Answer (score 1):

use this if you want more customization option

```
alertDialogue.setContentView(/*Layout*/)
```

or if you want some choices use this.

```
alertDialogue.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.toppings, null,
                      new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                       boolean isChecked) {
                   if (isChecked) {
                       // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                       mSelectedItems.add(which);
                   } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                       // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                       mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                   }
               }
           })
```

check the [android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I must use onSingleChoiceItems in fact,so you can show me the right way to do that?

Comment: use Array with One Value

Comment: I'll try this now